# Using Dapper to return list of objects, each parent containing two other objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, dapper

I'm new to Dapper, and have a 3 model class example. The SQL Database has associated tables for each model below.

My aim is to populate a list of Job objects (ie. all records in the Job table), each containing its associated Status & Client objects. How would this be achieved using Dapper?

Thank you kindly for any help you can give me!

The SQL will be :

`SELECT j.*, s.*, c.* FROM Job j INNER JOIN Status s ON j.StatusId = s.Id INNER JOIN Client ON j.ClientId = c.Id;`

The models are :

```
    public class StatusModel
    {
          public int Id { get; set; }
          public string StatusName { get; set; }
    }


   public class ClientModel
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string ClientName { get; set; }
      
   }


    public class JobModel
    {

      public int Id { get; }

      public string Description { get; set; }

      public StatusModel Status {get; set; }
      public ClientModel Client { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Dapper's multimap feature.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var jobs = await connection.QueryAsync<JobModel, StatusModel, ClientModel, JobModel>(sql, (job, status, client) =>
    {
        job.Status = status;
        job.Client = client;
        return job;
    }, splitOn: "StatusID,ClientID");   
}
```

You can read more [here](https://www.learndapper.com/relationships).

Comment: I needed to make a small change to above for it to work for me : ```splitOn: "Id,Id");```

Thank you mr.coffee!